# Remove blogger shadow from sidebars

Tags: blogger, shadow

I managed to find HTML code to remove main body shadow from my blogger but I can't do it with the sidebars. Any ideas appreciated very much cause it's not nice visually.

[see my blog](http://www.efriend.gr)

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add some code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS** paste this CSS code then click **Apply to Blog**

```
.main-inner .widget { box-shadow: none; }
```

Comment: how about the footer shadow? do u may know?

Comment: To remove shadow from footer use add this `.footer-fauxborder-left { box-shadow: none; }` like the previous method.

Comment: didit work for some reason.. i have in css this now:

.main-inner .widget { box-shadow: none; }    "(((enter)))"   
.footer-fauxborder-left { box-shadow: none; }

but footer if you see my site again its in the middle center, maybe this helps u?

Comment: Ok, you also need to remove it from blog pager and you can combine that by replacing all previous code with `.main-inner .widget, .footer-fauxborder-left, #blog-pager { box-shadow: none; }`